# Have ever had vs ever had

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

What's the right thing to say?
"Best meal I have ever had"
or
"Best meal I ever had"

Answer (score 1):

I think the first sentence is grammatically more accurate. We usually use "ever", "never", already", "yet" with present perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple but neither choice is a full sentence. **Both are sentence fragments.**

"Best meal I have ever had." [formal and standard]
or
"Best meal I ever had." [informal and colloquial]

Not to be used when dining with the Queen of England. [joke to emphasize a point]. However, if you're hanging out with certain American politicians, it's fine. [another joke to emphasize a point.]